# Is the __constructor function "special" or is it just a common function pre-written for facilitation?

Tags: php, constructor

```
class Person {
            public $isAlive = true;
            public $firstname;
            public $lastname;
            public $age;

            public function __construct($firstname, $lastname, $age) {
              $this->firstname = $firstname;
              $this->lastname = $lastname;
              $this->age = $age;
            }
```

Hi, I wanted some clarification about constructors. Is it a simple variable initializer that can be replicated manually or has special stuff built-in that makes it unique?
I mean if I had to create a function that does the same exact thing, what would be the difference compared to __construct?

As of now I feel like it's just a facilitation of something that you would do anyway, but I'm not entirely sure. The question is related to PHP, but I think that every contructor is built this way. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Recommended read: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Answer (score 0):

`__construct()` is a [magic method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php), called "automagically" when the class is instatiated (ie, when you use `new Person(...)`. In that regard, it is special and unique. There is a lot of information about how constructors work and what they do in the [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#object.construct).

You don't have to define a constructor; but if you do, then the logic that you code into it is entirely up to you.... and you can always put that logic in other public methods, that you have to call explicitly to execute them.

The are only two other significant differences between `__construct()` and other class methods is that you cannot return a value from the constructor. It only returns the instantiated object, and you cannot change that. And secondly, if the contructor fails, it will (automagically) throw an exception rather than intantiate the class.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor is the first function that gets called automatically when an instance of the class is created.

If you have the following class:

```
class Person
{
    function __construct($firstName, $lastName, $email)
    {
         $this->firstName = $firstName;
         $this->lastName = $lastName;
         $this->email = $email;
    }


    $firstName;
    $lastName;
    $age;
}
```

you can initialize a new object like this:

`$person = new Person("FirstName", "LastName", 30);`

You can't create a function that will behave exactly like the constructor. Yes you could create a function that will initialize the object like this:

```
function initialize($firstName, $lastName, $email)
{
     $this->firstName = $firstName;
     $this->lastName = $lastName;
     $this->email = $email;
}
```

but then you would either need to call the function immediately after instantiating a new object:

```
$person = new Person();
$person->initialize("FirstName", "LastName", 30);
```

or you would have to call it from within the constructor like this:

```
function __construct($firstName, $lastName, $email)
{
     $this->initialize($firstName, $lastName, $email);
}
```

The second way is rather common but the first one is very inefficient and should not be used. Either way you cannot imitate the constructor's functionality without using the constructor.

Comment: Thank you! Also the constructor gets called even if I don't write it down, correct? I mean I have no reason to actually write down the constructor if I don't want to assign any variable at the initialization of the instance, right?

Also, in the end, there's really no reason to make a "self-made" constructor from what I understand.

Comment: If you don't explicitly declare a constructor, the default (empty) constructor will be defined for you by default. No there is no need to create a self-made constructor but there are multiple reasons to implement a constructor depending on your use case